# Retrieving the Min element in a stack in O(1) Time

Tags: performance, algorithm, data-structures, stack

The reason I'm asking this question is because I cannot see why the way I think cannot be applied to this particular question

*"How would you design a stack which, 
in addition to push and pop, also has a function min which returns the minimum element? Push, pop and min should all operate in O(1) time*"

**My basic solution:** Wouldn't it be possible if we had a variable in **stack** class, that whenever we were pushing an item to stack we would check if it is **smaller** than our **min** variable. If it is assign the value to the min, if not ignore.

You would still get the O(1) as the min function would be;

```
int getMinimum(){
  return min;
}
```

Why this solution is never mentioned, or what is the fault with the way I think?

Comment: What if the minimum element is popped off the stack? How would you find the new minimum in O(1) time?

Comment: @SebastianPaaskeTørholm Thanks a lot. I got it now

Comment: possible duplicate of [design a stack such that getMinimum( ) should be O(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685060/design-a-stack-such-that-getminimum-should-be-o1)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This wouldn't work if you popped numbers off the stack.

Ex. 2,4,5,3,1. After you pop 1 off, what is your minimum?

The solution is to keep a stack of minimums, not just a single value. If you encounter a value that is less than equal to the current minimum, you need to push it onto the min-stack.

Ex.

```
Push(4):
Stack: 4
Min-stack: 4

Push(2):
Stack: 4 2
Min-stack: 4 2

Push(2):
Stack: 4 2 2
Min-stack: 4 2 2

Push(5):
Stack: 4 2 2 5
Min-stack: 4 2 2

Push(3):
Stack: 4 2 2 5 3
Min-stack: 4 2 2

Push(1):
Stack: 4 2 2 5 3 1
Min-stack: 4 2 2 1

Pop():
Stack: 4 2 2 5 3
Min-stack: 4 2 2

Pop():
Stack: 4 2 2 5
Min-stack: 4 2 2

Pop():
Stack: 4 2 2
Min-stack: 4 2 2

Pop():
Stack: 4 2
Min-stack: 4 2

Pop():
Stack: 4
Min-stack: 4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally got the idea.

Comment: Sure. After the time thing ends :D

Comment: You need to push also equal elements to the minimum stack. I'm not sure whether you intended that or not, but it should be explicitly mentioned.

Comment: Good call. I wanted to keep my example brief, but I'll add it in.

Answer (score 1):

Use a linked list to keep track of the minimum value which is gonna be the head.

Note that linkedlist.app= append ( we put the value in the tail ).
linkedlist.pre =prepend ( we put the value as the head of the linkedlist)

public class Stack {

```
int[] elements;
int top;
Linkedlists min;

public Stack(int n) {
    elements = new int[n];
    top = 0;
    min = new Linkedlists();
}

public void realloc(int n) {
    int[] tab = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < top; i++) {
        tab[i] = elements[i];
    }

    elements = tab;
}

public void push(int x) {
    if (top == elements.length) {
        realloc(elements.length * 2);
    }
    if (top == 0) {
        min.pre(x);
    } else if (x < min.head.data) {
        min.pre(x);
    } else {
        min.app(x);
    }
    elements[top++] = x;
}

public int pop() {

    int x = elements[--top];
    if (top == 0) {

    }
    if (this.getMin() == x) {
        min.head = min.head.next;
    }
    elements[top] = 0;
    if (4 * top < elements.length) {
        realloc((elements.length + 1) / 2);
    }

    return x;
}

public void display() {
    for (Object x : elements) {
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    }

}

public int getMin() {
    if (top == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return this.min.head.data;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack stack = new Stack(4);
    stack.push(2);
    stack.push(3);
    stack.push(1);
    stack.push(4);
    stack.push(5);
    stack.pop();
    stack.pop();
    stack.pop();
    stack.push(1);
    stack.pop();
    stack.pop();
    stack.pop();
    stack.push(2);
    System.out.println(stack.getMin());
    stack.display();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution [here](http://leetcode.com/2010/11/stack-that-supports-push-pop-and-getmin.html)

```
struct StackGetMin {
  void push(int x) {
    elements.push(x);
    if (minStack.empty() || x <= minStack.top())
      minStack.push(x);
  }
  bool pop() {
    if (elements.empty()) return false;
    if (elements.top() == minStack.top())
      minStack.pop();
    elements.pop();
    return true;
  }
  bool getMin(int &min) {
    if (minStack.empty()) {
      return false;
    } else {
      min = minStack.top();
      return true;
    }
  }
  stack<int> elements;
  stack<int> minStack;
};
```