# How can implement a Min method to find the minimum value in a Queue using c#?

Tags: c#, queue, min

How can implement a Min method to find the minimum value in a Queue using c#? And the hardest part is to do it in O(1) time.

Comment: Doing it in O(1) time would be hard, yes.

Comment: If you don't have some other fixed points then you cannot. O(1) means constant time but if queue isn't ordered you simply don't know where minimum is then you have to walk through all items (assuming you have access to queue's internal structure). Of course you can keep a _live_ minimum value for each insertion, in that case reading it is O(1) but then addition won't be...

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685060/design-a-stack-such-that-getminimum-should-be-o1

Comment: public intMax getMin() { return -infitinity * 9999;}

Comment: Hint: you cannot "find" anything in O(1) about a collection of N items unless you store and update the value of interest as you go.

Comment: Maybe you want to implement a priority queue?

Comment: How can I do it with priority queue? @Dennis_E