# Stack that returns the minimum value in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a stack that apart from offering the standard push and pop also returns the minimum value in `O(1)` time.

This is my code.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class MinStack<T> {

    private Node head;
    private Node minHead;
    private T minValue;


    private class Node<T extends Comparable<T>>  {
        private T data;
        private Node next;

        public Node(T data){
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }

        public int compareTo(T other){
            return data.compareTo(other);
        }

    }

    public void push(T item){
        Node p = new Node((Comparable) item);
        if(head == null){
            head = p;
            minHead = p;
            return;
        }
        p.next = head;
        head = p;

        if(((Comparable) item).compareTo(minValue) < 0){
            minValue = item;
            Node m = new Node((Comparable) item);
            m.next = minHead;
            minHead = m;
        }

    }

    public T pop(){
        if(head == null){
            System.out.println("Popping off an empty stack!!!");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        Node item = (Node) head.data;
        if(item == minValue){
            minHead = minHead.next;
        }
        head = head.next;
        return (T) item;
    }

    public T getMin(){
        return minValue;
    }

    public void trace(){
        Node current = head;
        while(current != null){
            if(current.next == null){
              System.out.println(current.data);
            }else{
                System.out.println(current.data + "->");
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

    public void minTrace(){
        Node current = minHead;
        while(current != null){
            if(current.next == null){
                System.out.println(current.data);
            }else{
                System.out.println(current.data + "->");
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

When i use the following client code,

```
MinStack<Integer> stack = new MinStack<>();
        stack.push(12);
        stack.push(1);
        stack.push(7);
        stack.push(9);
        stack.push(3);
        stack.push(2);
        stack.trace();
```

I get a `null pointer exception` at the line where the T values are compared using the compareTo function. Can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Is it because minValue is not initialised to anything?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(head == null){
            head = p;
            minHead = p;
            minValue = //try setting minvalue here
            return;
        }
```

When there's only one element, minValue will be equal to that element.

Comment: what happens when you pop the min value?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `null pointer exception` because your `minValue` is not initialised. Before using it try to initialise with some default value.

Moreover your intention seems to find a the lowest value from a data structure. In this case `Stack` is not a good solution. I will reccomend you to use `Priority Queue`.

And also [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/685069/1084174) might help you if you still go with Stack.